# Vote To Re-Open to Find Answer

Tags: discussion

**Mainly for users with 3k+ rep**

Straight to the point:

> Should we VTRO to find out what the OP had in mind as the answer when they posted the question?

On a [recent question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48595/the-puzzling-phone), the question was originally closed due to broadness/mathematical calculations.

However, some people would like to know the answer the OP had in mind, to see whether the question should be re-opened. The OP has said they will post the intended solution if and only if the question is re-opened. But we have no indication as to the quality of the solution.

The question here is whether we should re-open a closed question to find an answer that may or may not be good, just on curiosity. If we do, some users worry it may set a precedent that cannot be shaken off.

So, what does the community think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Strongly in favor of NOT doing this

This would set a dangerous precedent that someone can just tease that they have a fantastic answer to their dubious question to get it reopened.  ***A bad question is a bad question.***  If they can salvage the question by adding, say, [commentary that it *isn't* what it appears to be](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/jumping-on-the-bandwagon)<sup><sup>1</sup></sup> and has an actual, non-trivial, on-topic answer that is properly solvable from the content of the question itself, then that should probably have been part of the question in the first place.  The whole idea of the text

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

present right there in the "this question is closed" text speaks exactly to the possibility of doing this, and is the question poser's (sole, IMHO) remedy to questions being closed hastily.

_________
<sup><sup>1</sup>The disclaimer in this case was present from the beginning, but the idea holds.</sup>